# Calculation of no of hours & more on using date Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have below 2 dates with hours & time.
Format: Y-m-d H:i:s

```
$day1 = 2016-10-01 02:00:00
$day2 = 2016-10-02 03:00:00
```

calculating no of days using

```
$interval = $day1->diff($day2);
echo $interval->format('%a');
```

this gives me 1 day but actually it must be 2 days cause it more than 25hours.

So on the basis of hours how can we get no of days?

Comment: The difference is 1 day and 1 hour, so when you format it, it's just one day

Comment: Think of it like this: If you're looking at the time at 8am Monday morning, and again 9am Tuesday morning - how many hours have passed? 25. How many days have passed? Just 1.

Comment: @Qirel but wanna display days as 2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you mentioned, we are supposed to round it to the next day value if it exceeds 24 hrs.

The logic is pretty simple.

1. Store the hour difference between two dates in `$hoursDiff`.
2. Calculate the no. of days i.e the floor value `$days`.
3. Check if there's any additional difference e.g 1 day + remaining 1 hour `$remaining`
4. If remaining value exists then add 1 day to `$day`. Otherwise keep it as it is.

   ```
   $day1 = '2016-10-01 02:00:00'; // Declare as string
   $day2 = '2016-10-02 03:00:00'; // Declare as string
   $hoursDiff = round((strtotime($day2) - strtotime($day1))/3600, 1); 
   $days = floor($hoursDiff / 24); 
   $remaining = ($hoursDiff % 24);
   $dayDiff = $remaining ? ($days + 1) : $days;
   ```

Comment: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, on this line: $hoursDiff = round((strtotime($day2) - strtotime($day1))/3600, 1); @Object Manipulator

Comment: I think you're using the DateTime object here. You need to specify the dates as string.

Comment: AWESOME!

How can we have date changed if hours exceed like 3hours extra?